# Ascending chain of ideal in polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have an ideal $I_{1}=\langle x^5+x\rangle$, I have to find the largest $n$ so that
$I_{1} \subset I_{2} \subset ... \subset I_{n} \subset \mathbb{Q}[x] $.
I was thinking since $a|b \iff \langle b\rangle  \subset \langle a\rangle$ and $x^5-x=x(x^4-1)=x(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$ so there are four divisors of this polymonial, hence $n=4$. I'm not sure though if my reasoning is fine.

Comment: First of all, $x(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1) = x^5 - x$, so your factorisation is not quite right. That aside, can you explain why $x^5 + x$ having four irreducible factors would imply that $n = 4$?

Comment: Oh, I meant $x^2-x$. Well, this factors are its divisors so using the equivalence below we get 4. For example $\left \langle  x^5-x\right \rangle \subset  \left \langle  (x^2+1)(x^2-1) \right \rangle...$

Comment: Yep, seems good to me. The question still has some inconsistencies regarding this $\pm$ thing, so it might be worth fixing that for people who come across it in future.

Comment: Right, I'll fix this, thanks ;)

Comment: Your reasoning is absolutely fine, but just as a fun extra, note that this $n$ is the same as the maximum length of a chain of ideals in $R = \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^5-x\rangle$. By Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can decompose $R$ as a direct product of four fields: $R = \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x \rangle \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle \times\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x+1\rangle \times\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$. The ideals of a direct product of fields are precisely the direct products of subsets of the fields (see if you can prove that), so a chain will definitely have length $4$.

Comment: Just another way of thinking about it, and I think this argument is a bit more concrete, so it's less likely to have errors.